# Listener fo KeyChain Android

Tags: android, keychain

I have used

```
KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias
```

I have successfully extracted the Private Key as well as the Public Key.

I want to handle the Click Listener of KeyChain, whether the user has allowed or deny the installation of certificates.

I couldnt find anything in the developers documentation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

On Android ICS phone I have imported the `PKCS#12` file containing private key and certificate. Then i run

```
KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, this, new String[] { "RSA" }, null, null, -1, null);
```

In the certificate selection dialog i choose the one just installed.

In the 'alias' callback i do the following:

```
public void alias(final String alias) {
    ...
    protected Boolean[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ...
        PrivateKey pk = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(ctx, alias);
        Log.d(TAG, "EncodedPrivateKey: " + pk.toString());
```

And it gives me the full content of the private key.

Does it mean that any application, once allowed by user (in the cert. selection dialog), can read any private key installed from .pfx file?

Is the following scenario possible by standard Android means - "administrator" installing .pfx file with the cert.+private key and the permissions to read it are limited to the one specific app?

Comment: No @user7677685 the Certificates and KEYS are not specific to a single app.
Once the Certificate is installed either manually or from the application itself, the Certificate is installed on the Android Device and not on/for the application.

It can easily be accessed from a different application.